# Удалить элемент из RecyclerView Drag and Drop

Tags: android, drag-n-drop

Мое приложение выводит картинки. [Здесь](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.us9ogahcd) я взял пример реализации `Grid Layouts`. Мне нужно реализовать такой функционал, чтобы при перетаскивании элемента на другой элемент (`ImageView` на `ImageView`) перетаскиваемый элемент удалялся. Я нашел такую реализацию [тут](https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/android-drag-and-drop_tutorial/). Соединил ее со найденной реализацией и заметил проблему. Если я зажимаю элемент и отвожу его к корзинке, то все хорошо, он удаляется, но переместить этот элемент в другое место у меня не получается, даже анимации перемещения нет. Я выяснил, что конфликтуют между собой класс `ClipData` и метод `onStartDrag()`. Вопрос: как реализовать функционал так, чтобы элементы перемещались между собой и могли удаляться при наведении на другую картинку, или, допустим, на верхнюю часть экрана (на `ActionBar`) удаляться из списка?
Вот код главной активности:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDragListener,
    OnStartDragListener {

private RecyclerListAdapter adapter;
private int draggedIndex = -1;
private ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper;
private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.trashcan_layout);

    adapter = new RecyclerListAdapter(this, this);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((String) relativeLayout.getTag());
            ClipData clipData = new ClipData((CharSequence) relativeLayout.getTag(), new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, item);
            relativeLayout.startDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(relativeLayout), null, 0);
            View trashCan = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.trash_can);
            trashCan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            trashCan.setOnDragListener(MainActivity.this);
            draggedIndex = position;
        }
    }));

    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
    mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


@Override
public void onStartDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    mItemTouchHelper.startDrag(viewHolder);
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // Drag has started
            // If called for trash resize the view and return true
            if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
                view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
                view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
                return true;
            } else // else check the mime type and set the view visibility
                if (dragEvent.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    return true;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            // Drag has entered view bounds
            // If called for trash can then scale it.
            if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
                view.animate().scaleX(1.5f);
                view.animate().scaleY(1.5f);
            }
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            // Drag exited view bounds
            // If called for trash can then reset it.
            if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
                view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
                view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
            }
            view.invalidate();
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            // Ignore this event
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // Dropped inside view bounds
            // If called for trash can then delete the item and reload the grid
            // view
            if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
                RecyclerListAdapter.mItems.remove(draggedIndex);
                draggedIndex = -1;
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            // Hide the trash can
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    findViewById(R.id.trash_can).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }, 100l);
            if (view.getId() == R.id.trash_can) {
                view.animate().scaleX(1.0f);
                view.animate().scaleY(1.0f);
            } else {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            // remove drag listeners
            view.setOnDragListener(null);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, решили ли Вы данную проблему или нет?

Comment: @evb нет, не решил. Но знаю как решить - изменить подход. Вообще не юзать recyclerView, он не для этих целей. Написать свою вьюху, типа GridCells и из листа ее отрисовывать.